# How do i get the value of an option in google scripts

Tags: html, google-apps-script

This is an example of some the code in my google script web app:

```
<form id="myForm">
<h1>Senior Portraits</h1>
<div id="nameSelector" class="block form-group">
    <label id="nameTitle" for="select">Find your name</label>
    <select id="select">
        <option selected>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
```

When a button is clicked the following code runs:

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                return false;">
```

At which point the fileUploaded method in server.gs runs.
How do i get the value of my selector inside of server.gs?

Comment: Does the form have other user inputs/choices other than the drop down box?

Comment: Only an `<input type="file" name="myFile">`

Comment: The `<select>` tag should also have a `name` attribute.  You are getting the parentNode, which is the form.  That's good.  But when Apps Script processes the form element, it strips out everything but the data associated with the name attribute.  If you send the form object to the server, the only way to get the data out, is by referencing the name property.  There are other ways to collect and send the data, but if you get the form, you can't use anything but the name property to get the data out of the object once it's at the server code.

Comment: So I have a name for select now, but how do i get at the data in my code.gs?

Comment: Your `uploadFiles(receivedForm)` function should have an argument that receives the object.  Then you use the dot operator, and the name of the name attribute.  `var theOptionIs = receivedForm.theName`

Comment: Awesome thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: And when you send a form object, Apps Script won't allow anything else to be sent.  You can send lots of individual strings, or lots of individual arrays, or both.  But it you send a form object, it won't let you send anything else with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've pasted a quick edit below - moving the function out of that onClick, and grabbing the value with a quick getElementById. You want to get the value of the select, and pass that on.

```
<script>
function beginSubmit(){
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById('select').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(selectedValue);
}

</script>

<form id="myForm">
<h1>Senior Portraits</h1>
<div id="nameSelector" class="block form-group">
    <label id="nameTitle" for="select">Find your name</label>
    <select id="select">
        <option selected>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" onclick="beginSubmit()">
```

Edit: May also be useful to take a look at [acceptable parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) between HTML and Google scripts

Comment: if i call selectedValue, is it going to be a string of the value in the menu?

Comment: @dafly45 it'll grab a string, but you can send an array, object, etc through the Google.Script.run - I noticed the file uploaded part, are you looking to get a file on the HTML side and send it through? I'd imagine you can send a blob through, but I've never actually done it myself

Comment: Yea, I'm doing it with a blob right now, for some reason the string couldn't be passed through

Comment: I'd expect the other way around, but I don't see why it wouldn't take a string. I tested what I put above before posting and it worked on my end - is there anything else in your code that might be affecting it? Or is everything still the same as your original post?

Comment: Im getting the following error:

    Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: Forms with file inputs must be the only parameter.

Comment: Would it work if i set the value of a label or something as the selected option because then it would be part of the form?

Comment: Confused by the second comment - is the form larger than what you provided above? Specifically ( in regards to the first comment) is there a type='file' field?

Comment: Yes there is a file field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88526/discussion-between-dafly45-and-jens-astrup).